# How to fix parsing of textfile?

Tags: python, readline

I am trying to parse a text file, from then I can decide whether or not it is above the line `y=x`, on, on or below. The code runs through, but is not executing my `readline()`s.

My text file I am using is this:

```
4
2
1
3
3
5
6
7
8
```

I have altered the code by doing different forms of the `readline()`.

```
if res == "yes":
    with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
        alist = [line.rstrip() for line in f]
        timesgo = 0
        terms = f.readline()
        while str(terms) > str(timesgo):
            temp = f.readline()
            y = f.readline()
            if temp < y:
                u = str(temp) + "," + str(y)
                Above.append(u)
                timesgo += 1
            elif temp == y:
                u = str(temp) + "," + str(y)
                On.append(u)
                timesgo += 1
            if temp > y:
                u = str(temp) + "," + str(y)
                Below.append(u)
                timesgo += 1
```

I expect to have 4 coordinates in total, in the case of the file: `(2,1)`, `(3,3)`, `(5,6)`, `(7,8)` should appended to the appropriate list to then be sorted in by further code.

Comment: if you use `for line in f` then you are at the end of file and `readline()` has nothing to read. You have all lines in `alist` and you should use this list instead of `f.readline()`

Comment: instead of `timesgo = 0`, `while str(terms) > str(timesgo):` and many `timesgo += 1` you could use only one `for x in range(int(terms)):`

Comment: you could do only once `u = str(temp) + "," + str(y)`. If you need it later as numbers then better keep it as list or tuple `u = (temp, y)`

Comment: The  term "`import`" has [special significance](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#import) in Python, and that's _not_ what it appears you are trying to do — so I have modified your question according.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My version:

```
if res == "yes":
    with open('text.txt') as f:
        terms = f.readline()
        for _ in range(int(terms)):

            x = int(f.readline())
            y = int(f.readline())

            #u = (x, y)              # as tuple with numbers
            u = "{},{}".format(x, y) # as string

            if x < y:
                Above.append(u)
            elif x > y:
                Below.append(u)
            else
                On.append(u)
```

Your mistake was

```
alist = [line.rstrip() for line in f]
```

which was reading all lines from file and later `readline()` had nothing to read.

The other changes are only cosmetic.